# base64 string won't convert to image

Tags: javascript, php, html, base64

I have the below base64 string generated from an app I'm testing out. It's supposed to generate an image but I can seem to get it to validate or display in HTML. I am trying to use PHP to decode and change to a JPG file but it seems the source of the base64 string may be the issue. Any thoughts?

I actually linked the file with the base64 in [here](http://fanbeauties.com/base64String.txt) since it's so many characters.

Thanks in advance!

PHP Code:

```
$title = $_POST['name'];
$market = $_POST['market'];
$account = "414890";
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
$image = $_POST['picture'];
$title = $_POST['name'];
$source_type = "app";

if($pass == "Fan412") { 
    //Convert base64 into image
    $filename_path = md5(time().uniqid()).".jpg";
    $decoded=base64_decode($image);
    file_put_contents("../FOLDER_TO_IMAGES/".$filename_path,$decoded);

    // Insert Info into Database
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO TABLE_HERE (account, date, source_type, title, market, image) VALUES ('$account', '$date', '$source_type', '$title', '$market', '$filename_path')");            

    // close connection 
    $mysqli->close();
} else {
    die();
}
```

Comment: Please include your PHP code. Do you get any errors?

Comment: @showdev I just edited the post with the PHP code added.

Comment: Why would you first encode then immediately decode the image? Also what is `$_POST['picture']`

Comment: @christianm Sorry I meant to delete that encode line. The $_POST[‘picture’] is the base64 string as shown in the linked file.

Comment: Btw. I just checked locally and also can't seem to make this a working image. It looks okay-ish superficially when decoded, but apparently something is wrong in the data.

Comment: @ChristianM How did you even get it to display? I can't even get a photo image.

Comment: Exactly, I can't neither. I just looked at the raw output and you can see some sensible metadata in there. So it looks like it could be an image, but something is wrong in there.

Comment: Seems the source is bad, which makes the rest of your code go bonkers. If you can get a clean working source that is properly base64 encoded... then this may all just work out as you expect.